# Why does Vim treat the `<link>` tag in XML files differently?

Tags: filetype-xml

I've noticed that omnicomplete and keyboard motions don't work in XML files with a `<link>` tag as expected. For example

```
<related-links scope="external" format="html">
    <link href="www.example.org">
        <linktext>Example Link</linktext>
    </link>
</related-links>
```

If I put the cursor within the `<link>...</link>` block and press <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>, I would expect to select lines 2-4. Instead it selects the outer tag (`<related-links>` in this case).

Another example of this issue happened with the following XML file:

```
<related-links scope="external" format="html">
    <link href="www.example.org">
        <linktext>Example Link</linktext>
```

I should be able to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to invoke omnicomplete to close the `<link>` tag. Instead it skips it and closes the `<related-links>` tag instead.

I've noticed this issue with a few different versions of Vim. Is this the intended behavior of the built-in XML ft? If so, why?

**Edit:**
I *am* able to reproduce this with `vim --noplugin -u NONE -N` (if I set `:filetype indent plugin on` after starting Vim). This was with Vim 7.2.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your first issue, the selection works fine here. Can you have a look at this post: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file

Comment: Same here the selection works fine.

Comment: @Nobe4 This issue actually persists for me, even starting vim without my vimrc and plugins.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: I still cannot reproduce, this without any plugin/configuration...

Comment: Solaris 5.10. Although I've seen this issue on Windows XP and 7 too...

Comment: I tried with http://coolwanglu.github.io/vim.js/emterpreter/vim.html and it still select correctly ... I don't really understand what's going on here...

Comment: Vim 7.2 is eight years old. You should try with a newer version one day.